# Command GET-DBAOPERATINGSYSTEM: can a time out be set on this command?

Tags: dbatools

Hi DBATOOLS Community,

I'm using this great DBA powershell module to put in place a report script that will gather several metrics from all SQL Server I have in the company. 
But sometimes the **GET-DBAOPERATINGSYSTEM** command just get stacked with out any output for hours ! ( just had to stop the run of my script after nearly 2 hours run on only this command ! ).
 So my questions are:
1. **Do you have any idea why this command just got stack ?**
2. **Can a time out be specified to this command a how can it be set ?**

Many Thanks for your answers.

```
$OsVersion= Get-DbaOperatingSystem -ComputerName $servername | SELECT ComputerName , Version
```

Comment: If you look in the Operational log for Powershell can you see what the last process to run is before it gets stuck?